# I got a problem during post request in django

Tags: django, forms, post, form-submit

I want to send my data through post request. I used postgres database.

I also tried for makemigrations and migrate this model, it also shows the error message.

When i tried to submit my form, it shows following error.

```
IntegrityError at /formSubmit
null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (Own, Khar, 3, 23, 2323, 23233, 324, null).
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/formSubmit
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (Own, Khar, 3, 23, 2323, 23233, 324, null).
Exception Location: D:\coding time\Django+ GeoDjango\Django 
Enviroment\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute, 
line 85
Python Executable:  D:\coding time\Django+ GeoDjango\Django 
Enviroment\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.2
```

my models.py file is comes form python manage.py inspectdb command. I managed the database in postgres. models.py file is here:

```
class Form(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=29, blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'form'

class Ownership(models.Model):
    house_no = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    ward_no = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    tole = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    house_owner = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    religion = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ownership'


class Residence(models.Model):
    ownership_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    house_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    land_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    total_room = models.CharField(max_length=101, blank=True, null=True)
    house_use = models.CharField(max_length=101, blank=True, null=True)
    house_area = models.CharField(max_length=101, blank=True, null=True)
    earthquake_resistance = models.CharField(max_length=101, blank=True, null=True)
    id = models.ForeignKey(Ownership, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'residence'


class ServiceDetail(models.Model):
    radio = models.BooleanField(primary_key=True)
    television = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    telephone = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    computer = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    internet = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    motorcycle = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    car = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    refrigerator = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    washing_machine = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    heater = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    id = models.ForeignKey(Ownership, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'service_detail'
```

my form.html file is here:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>form</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
  width:100%;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: #fff;
}
table#t01 th {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action='/formSubmit'>
    {% csrf_token %}

        <h3>Ownership Detail</h3>
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
        Ward: <input type="text" name="ward"><br><br>
        tole name: <input type="text" name="tname"><br><br>
        House number: <input type="text" name="hnumber"><br><br>
        Gender: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Female<br><br>
        Religeous: <select name="religeous">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option>Hindu</option>
                    <option>Buddhist</option>
                    <option>Islam</option>
                    <option>Isai</option>
                </select>
    <br><br>
    language: <input type="text" name="language"> <br><br>

        <h3>Residence Detail</h3>
        Owner type: <select name="ownertype"><option>select</option><option>Own</option><option>Lease</option><option>Corporation</option></select><br><br>
        House type: <select name="housetype">
                        <option>select</option>
                        <option>Khar</option>
                        <option>Tin</option>
                        <option>Cement</option>
                        <option>Stone</option>
                    </select><br><br>
        Land type: <input type="text" name="landtype"><br><br> 
        Total room: <input type="text" name="totalroom"><br><br>
        House used: <input type="text" name="houseused"><br><br>
        House area: <input type="text" name="housearea"><br><br>
        Earthquake resistance: <input type="text" name="earthquake"><br><br>

        <h3>Service Detail</h3>
        <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Facilities</th>
    <th>Yes/no</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Radio</td>
    <td><select name="radio"><option>Yes</option><option>No</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TV</td>
    <td><select name="tv"><option>Yes</option><option>No</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mobile</td>
    <td><select name="mobile"><option>Yes</option><option>No</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>computer</td>
      <td><select name="computer"><option>Yes</option><option>No</option></select></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Internet</td>
    <td><select name="internet"><option>Yes</option><option>No</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MoterCycle</td>
    <td><select name="motercycle"><option>Yes</option><option>No</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Car</td>
    <td><select name="car"><option>Yes</option><option>No</option></select></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Hitar</td>
    <td><select name="hitar"><option>Yes</option><option>No</option></select></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<br><br>

<p align="center"><button type="submit" name="submit">Submit Data</button></p>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my views.py file is here:

```
from .models import Form, Residence, Ownership, ServiceDetail
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    form = Form.objects.all()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def form(request):
    return render(request, 'form.html')

def submit(request):
    name = request.POST['name']
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']


    info = Form(name=name, email=email, password=password)
    info.save()

    return render(request, 'submit.html')

def formSubmit(request):
    name = request.POST['name']
    ward = request.POST['ward']
    tname = request.POST['tname']
    hnumber = request.POST['hnumber']
    gender = request.POST['gender']
    religeous = request.POST['religeous']
    language = request.POST['language']
    ownertype = request.POST['ownertype']
    housetype = request.POST['housetype']
    landtype = request.POST['landtype']
    totalroom = request.POST['totalroom']
    houseused = request.POST['houseused']
    housearea = request.POST['housearea']
    earthquake = request.POST['earthquake']
    radio = request.POST['radio']
    tv = request.POST['tv']
    computer = request.POST['computer']
    mobile = request.POST['mobile']
    internet = request.POST['internet']
    motercycle = request.POST['motercycle']
    car = request.POST['car']
    hitar = request.POST['hitar']

    def count(n):
        for i in range(n):
            return i
            if i == n:
                return n+1

    ownership = Ownership(house_no=hnumber, ward_no=ward, tole=tname, house_owner=name, gender=gender, religion=religeous, language=language)
    ownership.save()

    residence = Residence(ownership_type=ownertype, house_type=housetype, land_type=landtype, total_room=totalroom, house_use=houseused, house_area=housearea, earthquake_resistance=earthquake)
    residence.save()

    serviceDetail = ServiceDetail(radio=radio, television=tv, computer=computer, internet= internet, motorcycle=motercycle, car=car, heater=hitar)
    serviceDetail.save()

    return render(request, 'submit.html')
```

my urls.py file is here:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('form', views.form, name = 'form'),
    path('submit', views.submit, name = 'submit'),
    path('formSubmit', views.formSubmit, name= 'formSubmit')
]
```

Comment: Try using `Ownership.objects.create` instead of what you're currently doing. Same for `Residence` and `ServiceDetail`.

Comment: Can you please specify where should i try `Ownership.objects.create` ? I just want to save the post request.

Comment: Actually, it's because you're creating `Residence` and `ServiceDetail`s without giving them `id`s which need to be an `Ownership`.  This is in your `formSubmit` function. Btw, Python coding standard is to have snake case function names. So you should call it `form_submit`.

Comment: Either way, I recommend using `objects.create` as mentioned earlier. And maybe add `primary_key=True` when you redefine a model's `id`.